Executing a save method with PK signed transaction to Polygon smart contract, from nodejs express post request
1.)
I tried to execute the call to a "save" transaction method to a smart contract on Polygon mainnet. I tried to do this from a nodejs script run on the sever. It works!, the transaction is beinng saved.
2.)
I tried to do the same thing from within a nodejs express POST request (calling the POST request from Postman). It does not work, it throws the error in cmd:
the nodejs code below:
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = 3003;
const Web3 = require('web3').default;
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');
const contractABI = ['someabi'];
const contractAddress = "some_address";
const privateKey = "private_key";
const polygonURL = "https://polygon-rpc.com";
const accountAddress = "account_address";

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/api', (req, res) => {

    const dataToSave = JSON.stringify(req.body.request.parameters);
    const web3 = new Web3(polygonURL);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
    const data = contract.methods.save(dataToSave).encodeABI();
    const privateKeyFinal = Uint8Array.from(Buffer.from(privateKey, 'hex'));

    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress, 'pending').then(nonce => {

        const txDetails = {
            chainId: 137,
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(nonce),
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(200000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.0001', 'gwei')), 
            to: contractAddress,
            value: '0x0',
            data: data
        };

        const tx = new Tx(txDetails, { 'chain': 'polygon' });
        tx.sign(privateKeyFinal);

        const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
            .then(receipt => {
                console.log('Transaction receipt:', receipt);
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'Data saved to Polygon blockchain successfully',
                    transactionHash: receipt.transactionHash
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred submitting the transaction', error: err.message });
            });
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'An error occurred fetching transaction count', error: err.message });
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});

I was expecting the transaction to be executed to "https://polygon-rpc.com", but it throws the error:
Error: crypto.getRandomValues must be defined

